# How to get cookie from selenium ide? or delete cookies to archive logout

Tags: java, testing, selenium

I have tried to get cookies using

```
..getCookie();
..getVookieByName(..);
```

but both methods does not return anything. I read that it is impossible to get cookie from selenium, because of HttpOnly, which actually I cannot switch.

Then I tried to perform:

```
..deleteAllVisibleCookies();
```

but no luck.

May there is some way how I can perform logout, or get the cookie from selenium?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of the cookie name you want to delete, you may use this:

**deleteCookie ( name,optionsString )**

> Delete a named cookie with specified path and domain. Be careful; to
> delete a cookie, you need to delete it using the exact same path and
> domain that were used to create the cookie. If the path is wrong, or
> the domain is wrong, the cookie simply won't be deleted. Also note
> that specifying a domain that isn't a subset of the current domain
> will usually fail. Since there's no way to discover at runtime the
> original path and domain of a given cookie, we've added an option
> called 'recurse' to try all sub-domains of the current domain with all
> paths that are a subset of the current path. Beware; this option can
> be slow. In big-O notation, it operates in O(n*m) time, where n is the
> number of dots in the domain name and m is the number of slashes in
> the path. Arguments:
>
> **name** - the name of the cookie to be deleted
>
> **optionsString** - options
> for the cookie. Currently supported options include 'path', 'domain'
> and 'recurse.'
> The optionsString's format is "path=/path/,
> domain=.foo.com, recurse=true". The order of options are irrelevant.
> Note that specifying a domain that isn't a subset of the current
> domain will usually fail.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium cannot access(and hence delete) **http-only** cookie. http-only indicates that the cookie can be accessed/modified only at server side.